# NDEigensystem boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I am attempting to solve the Schrodinger 1-D time independent equation for the eigenfunctions and eigen-energies of the piecewise potential described in the attached image of my code.  I need to determine the 50 lowest eigen-energies.  All values in atomic units. [image] However, I am only printing out 5 values, and recieving an error code of Lists {val, fun} are not the same shape. Additionally, I cannot force the boundary condition of R[r] to zero at the value of r=207.  I am unsure how to fix this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you and @getafix taking the same class? We got a similar [question on chat yesterday](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47282575#47282575) with a similar piece-wise linear potential. Also in terms of you problem, it'd be *much* easier to help if you post all your code instead of a screenshot... We generally help best if there's code we can copy. In terms of your issue, try putting the first two arguments in a list and providing `R[r]` in the second argument.

Comment: Also you only ask `NDEigensystem` for 5 eigenvalues, that is the 4th argument.